# App doesn't render the year in a single Post

Tags: bug, ios-app

[image]

Sorry for the lack of hand drawn red circle. The Post in question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265838/792066

- App Version: 1.6.0.3
- Device: iPhone 4S
- OS Version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)

Comment: Update your app ;)

Comment: @Cai I'm using the beta version...

Comment: Then you havn't updated it in a while, you're a fair few versions behind. Check the dupe, this was fixed in 1.6.0.8 (current is 1.6.0.10 I think—too lazy to check)

Comment: @Cai just now it updated... TestFlight is alright